# How to connect Google App Engine (PHP) with Cloud Datastore?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to connect my Local Development Site (using PHP) to Cloud Datastore, but unfortunately I do not know how to set up my code to reach the Datastore. I have tried the solution of tomwalder/php-gds, but I do not know, how to set up the code to work with my site. After the installation with composer, I do not know which file should be modified, there is no config.php in my directory. There are also no Google Documentation about Datastore for PHP. 
I am open for any solution to connect the Datastore with my site.

Can you please give us a few tips, how to start the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds. Tom just released a version that connects natively to the datastore, which is faster than going via Cloud Datastore.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, I have tried this solution, because it seems to be a very good code, but I don't really know how to connect with it. I have installed the necessary files with composer and downloaded the json key file for my service account, but I don't know what to do after that. Unfortunately I have not found a step by step documentation to this.

Comment: With the latest version you don't need to worry about the service accounts - it will autodetect and just use the native connection. Read through the instructions at the github site.

Comment: I have tried Tom's library again and it is working now. The new code is very easy to implement and work with. Thank you for your help, Stuart.

Comment: Thanks for the plug :-)